# Javascript: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I tested my site with the new IE 9 and I get the error telling me INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5). In IE 9, the developer tools highlights this line. Can anyone help me with this error?

Error Line

```
this.iframe = document.createElement('<IFRAME src="' + myCurrentUrl + '" frameborder=0>');


Function Code
__createDivs : function()
{
this.divs_transparentDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
this.divs_transparentDiv.className='modalDialog_transparentDivs';
this.divs_transparentDiv.style.left = '0px';
this.divs_transparentDiv.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(this.divs_transparentDiv);
this.divs_content = document.createElement('DIV');
this.divs_content.className = 'modalDialog_contentDiv';
this.divs_content.id = 'DHTMLSuite_modalBox_contentDiv';
this.divs_content.style.zIndex = 100000;
if(this.MSIE){
var myCurrentUrl = GlobPanelCurrentBaseUrl + 'images/spacer.gif';
this.iframe = document.createElement('<IFRAME src="' + myCurrentUrl + '" frameborder=0>');
this.iframe.style.zIndex = 90000;
this.iframe.style.position = 'absolute';
document.body.appendChild(this.iframe); 
}
document.body.appendChild(this.divs_content);
this.divs_shadow = document.createElement('DIV');
this.divs_shadow.className = 'modalDialog_contentDiv_shadow';
this.divs_shadow.style.zIndex = 95000;
document.body.appendChild(this.divs_shadow);
window.refToModMessage = this;
this.addEvent(window,'scroll',function(e){ window.refToModMessage.__repositionTransparentDiv() });
this.addEvent(window,'resize',function(e){ window.refToModMessage.__repositionTransparentDiv() });
}
```

Comment: FYI, older versions of IE allowed you to pass arbitrary HTML into createElement, but that's a violation of the specification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you're supposed to just give it the name of the element, then set properties on it like so:

```
this.iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
this.iframe.src = myCurrentUrl;
this.iframe.frameBorder = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just able to fix it using the following

this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
this.iframe.setAttribute("src", myCurrentUrl);
this.iframe.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;z-index:90000;");
this.iframe.frameBorder = 0;